# For each button i press, open the same form.(C#)

Tags: c#

I have some buttons in my main form. I want when i will press any button, opening the same form

my code (in form Load)

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
button btn = c as Button;
{
Table ss = new Table();
Hide();
ss.ShowDialog();
}
```

But it shows my form directly, and not when i click one of my buttons.

Comment: because that is the way you coded it.  use the cleverly named click event to show them when you...click

Comment: Thank you Sir, how will i do this? I have about 50 buttons and i want to avoid writing the code for each one button seperately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hook to the click events on the buttons to the same handler:

```
//on your form_load or on the constructor...
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    Button btn = c as Button;

    if(c == null)
        continue;

    c.Click += handle_click;
}

//on your form class
void handle_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Table ss = new Table();
    Hide();
    ss.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: I modified the code a bit to handle cases where the form contains controls whic aren't buttons.

Comment: Thank you Sir it works but what if i want to pass "button.Text" in my new form?      ss.label1.Text = this.btn.Text.ToString();?

Comment: ss.label1.Text = (sender as Button).Text; But your label must be public for it, a better approach is to expose a property on the Table form which sets the label text, then you can set this property from outside the form without accessing the internal controls.

Comment: Thank you Sir SO MUCH!! It is exactly what i was need!!It Works 100%!

Answer (score -2):

use a button click event like this

```
private void btnCustomize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Customize cz = new Customize();
        cz.Show();
    }
```

this will open the form you want when the button is pressed.

Comment: I bet you the user will sai "It doesn't works" and it's because he didn't hooked to the click event XD

Comment: No, the way i have it  in the answer is the way you open a form from a button. You just have to do this code for each button. What ever the name of the button is will be the click event. then the name of the form will be whatever he puts, i used the example Customize.

Comment: The user has 50 buttons, and don't want to create an event handler for each one, read the comments, it's about doing it programatically.

Comment: i f you want 10 forms to open up at the same time, then you would put all 10 forms in one button click event.

Comment: Programmatically, a button is a button. There is no function to it until you program what that button does. What he is doing is writing code to simulate a button that does not know what to do. He will have to program each button. If there is a way to just do an eight line code to manage all buttons and there functions, Programming will be a lot easier, and defy programming logic.

Comment: Please, learn a bit about event handlers, there are tons of ways of doing that in very little code, read my answer, it does exactly that.

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's question about how to use the same handler for all button clicks, as @Gusman answer's does.